# Плагин для предзаказа

Tags: woocommerce

Есть ли плагин для предзаказа в `woocommerce`, чтобы если товара нет в наличии то можно было заказать его?
И чтобы можно было просмотреть заказанные товары в админке

**P.S.**
и чтобы если товара нет в наличии, то на странице товара появлялась кнопка что-то типа "предзаказ"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Их несколько, искать надо по слову pre-order. Вот самый известный:

https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-pre-orders/

Comment: подскажите а есть ли бесплатный аналог этого плагина? хотя-бы чтобы были доступны функции просмотра предзаказов в админке

Comment: и чтобы если товара нет в наличии, то на странице товара появлялась кнопка что-то типа "предзаказ"

Comment: @Sevastopol' И с чего это вдруг такое мнение? Автор спросил "есть ли плагин", я ответил "есть несколько, вот такой, например".